# Post video to Facebook from Android with deep link back to app

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, facebook-share, deeplink

**Problem:** I'm trying to share content to Facebook from my Android app that is hosted somewhere else and have it deeplink back to my app.

**Details**
I'm developing and Android app and the problem I'm facing is I have a video that I want to share to the user's newsfeed with a deeplink back in to the app. The video is hosted on Cloudinary, but that is irrelevant, trying to post a Youtube video to a users newsfeed but have it deeplink back to the app when they click on the description below would be the same problem.

I've come really close using Facebook's `ShareLinkContent` and a `ShareDialog`. The code looks like this:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://kt4rh.app.goo.gl/naxy")) /* Deeplink back into my app created using Firebase Dynamic Link */
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse({path to an image stored on clodinary}))
                        .build();
                ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity());
                shareDialog.show(content);
```

This shows an **image**, with a deeplink back to my app when the user taps on it. However, what I want to do is show a **video** (or a gif, either would be fine) instead of the image.

I've tried downloading the video to the device and using a `ShareVideoContent`, hoping that I could set the `localUrl` and the `contentUrl` (similar to how I set the thumbnail and contentUrl in the `ShareLinkContent` above) like this:

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(localPathToVideo));
                ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
                        .setLocalUrl(videoUri)
                        .build();
                ShareVideoContent videoContent  = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                        .setVideo(shareVideo)
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://kt4rh.app.goo.gl/naxy")) /* Deeplink back to app */
                        .build();
                ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity());
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                if (shareDialog.canShow(videoContent)) {
                    shareDialog.show(videoContent);
                }
```

But I just get an error back saying "Only one of link, photos, and video should be specified.", meaning I can't set the local url and content url.

So now I'm stuck. Seems like this should be a relatively common issue (to share content hosted somewhere else and have it deeplink back to your app), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving this by creating an html page for every item to be shared (in this case trip itineraries) and hosting them on Firebase's Cloud Storage. Here's what the code looks like

```
/**
 * In order to share gifs to facebook and have a animating gif show up, we need to construct an arbitrary HTML page that wraps the
 * gif image that we want to share. When the user clicks on the wrapped html page, it will forward to the real page we want it to show.
 *
 * Facebook uses custom meta properties to determine what image to show in the preview, which is why we need to wrap the actual gif with another image this way
 */
private static final String GIF_IMAGE = "<gif_image_here>";
private static final String REDIRECT_LINK = "<redirect_link_here>";

private static final String SHARE_HTML_PAGE = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"video.other\" />" +
        "<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"" + GIF_IMAGE + "\" />" +
        "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"" + GIF_IMAGE + "\" />" +
        "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=" + REDIRECT_LINK + "\" />" +
        "</head></html>";

public static void shareGifToFacebook(final Activity activity, final String gifUrl, final Trip trip, final ShareStatusListener shareStatusListener) {
    String htmlPageToShare = SHARE_HTML_PAGE.replaceAll(GIF_IMAGE, gifUrl).replaceAll(REDIRECT_LINK, DeeplinkUtils.getTripDeeplink(trip.getUid()));

    // Upload the html page somewhere accessible
    FirebaseStorageUploader.uploadShareHtml(TravellerManager.getInstance().getCurrentlyLoggedInUserUid(), htmlPageToShare, new FirebaseStorageUploader.UploadShareHtmlListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String publicUrl) {
            Log.d("ShareUtils", "shareGifToFacebook() publicUrl to be shortened:  " + publicUrl);

            URLShortener.shortUrl(publicUrl, new URLShortener.LoadingCallback() {
                @Override
                public void startedLoading() {

                }

                @Override
                public void finishedLoading(@Nullable String shortUrl) {
                    Log.d("ShareUtils", "shareGifToFacebook() finishedLoading() shortenedUrl " + shortUrl);

                    ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(shortUrl))
                            .setContentDescription(activity.getString(R.string.view_trip_on_wd))
                            .setContentTitle(trip.getName())
                            .build();
                    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity);
                    shareDialog.show(content);

                    if (shareStatusListener != null) {
                        shareStatusListener.onShared();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed() {
            Toaster.toastLong(activity.getString(R.string.general_error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes it works @DevKRos. Yes the gif url is third party, I use Cloudinary to host the gifs

Comment: I am working on same set of problem .Need to share a image from third party url and click on image redirects to app but getting trouble sharing html string as content link .Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're just sharing an image just use a ShareLinkContent @DevkRos. See my original question for an example. It's only difficult if you're trying to share a video or gif.

Comment: yep i am sharing gif :/

Comment: Oh, you don't share the html @DevKRos. You have to host the html somewhere and then share the link to where it's hosted. In my example I upload the html to Firebase's cloud storage and then share the link that it generates.

Answer (score 0):

I think on Android you can't set the `contentUrl` and the Video simultaneously. I was getting the similar issue, but it worked after removing `.setContentUrl(...)`.

What you could do instead is copy the link to the clipboard and convince the user to paste the link into their caption (i.e.: show a pop-up / alert before opening up the `ShareDialog`).

There may be other ways around this. If so, I would love to know as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that route initially @Deon Nicholas but the user experience was brutal. I ended up finding a solution by creating an html page and storing that in Firebase Storage. I'll add an answer with more details